# Sort a number of PDF files in increasing order of page count using Perl

Tags: perl

Could anyone please suggest a logic on how to sort n number of PDF files in a folder according to the number of pages of each PDF file and write out the sorted list of PDF files in a text file?

For instance

```
file1.pdf - 50 pages
file2.pdf - 30 pages
file3.pdf - 75 pages
file4.pdf - 20 pages
.
.
file34.pdf - 7 pages
file35.pdf - 75 pages
```

Comparison of each file with the rest and sorting is not an optimal solution.
Another idea I had is to rename the files with its number of pages and somehow sort it to write out in a sorted order.

Please suggest if there are any libraries which do this. I am looking for a Perl-based solution.

Comment: Did you try something first?

Comment: I was planning to try with renaming files with number of pages as filename to have it sorted. Thought of getting some suggestions before doing that...

Comment: What do you mean by *"Comparison of each file with the rest and sorting is not an optimal solution."*? You've just asked *"how to sort n number of PDF files in a folder"*!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why this is a problem -- it's a very trivial task. Do you know any Perl at all? Unless you have trillions of PDF files then there is no need for any concern about efficiency, and I don't understand what you mean by *"Comparison of each file with the rest and sorting is not an optimal solution"*.

I recommend that you install [`PDF::API2`](https://metacpan.org/module/PDF::API2) to extract the number of pages in each document. Then it's just a matter of building a hash and sorting it. Whether that's *"optimal"* or not is irrelevant as it will take only a moment.

This example program shows the idea. I have used a documentation directory that I had on one of my Windows systems.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

use PDF::API2;
use List::Util 'max';

chdir '\\\\SAMURAI\C\ProgramData\Altova\SharedBetweenVersions\Apache FOP 1.1 JDK 1.4\docs\1.0';

my @files = glob '*.pdf';
my $width = max map length, @files;
my %page_counts;

for my $file (@files) {
  my $pdf = PDF::API2->open($file);
  $page_counts{$file} = $pdf->pages;
}

for my $file (sort { $page_counts{$a} <=> $page_counts{$b} } keys %page_counts) {
  printf "%-*s - %d pages\n", $width, $file, $page_counts{$file};
}
```

**output**

```
index.pdf                - 2 pages
accessibility.pdf        - 3 pages
compiling.pdf            - 3 pages
releaseNotes_1.0.pdf     - 3 pages
pdfa.pdf                 - 3 pages
pdfx.pdf                 - 3 pages
upgrading.pdf            - 3 pages
anttask.pdf              - 4 pages
pdfencryption.pdf        - 4 pages
metadata.pdf             - 4 pages
hyphenation.pdf          - 5 pages
knownissues_overview.pdf - 5 pages
servlets.pdf             - 6 pages
running.pdf              - 6 pages
extensions.pdf           - 6 pages
intermediate.pdf         - 7 pages
events.pdf               - 8 pages
graphics.pdf             - 8 pages
configuration.pdf        - 9 pages
fonts.pdf                - 9 pages
changes_1.0.pdf          - 10 pages
embedding.pdf            - 11 pages
output.pdf               - 21 pages
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and suggestion Borodin. I thought the code execution might take time to compare the files since I have to compare 1000+ pdf files on each run. <br/>I will use your suggestion and see if it doesn't struggle.

Comment: I used your logic for my requirement and it worked well. Thanks Borodin.

Answer (score 1):

With ImageMagick's `identify` command

```
identify -format "%n %f\n" *.pdf | sort -n
```

**Output**

```
16 a.pdf
29 b.pdf
```

Or use `pdfinfo` which is probably faster:

```
for f in *.pdf; do
  pages=$(pdfinfo "$f" | awk '/Pages:/{print $2}')
  echo $pages $f
done | sort -n
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mark. I will use the logic you suggested and the one Borodin had suggested below and see if which logic suits my requirement better.